# Bundles management in PHP

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I have a home-made framework which contains two types of bundles. Application bundles and dependencies. Application bundles are specific to the application (can be a news module, administration, etc.). Dependencies are libraries which I re-use in several projects.

For every new project, I start by adding the app bundles and dependencies. Until now I kept a separate copy of these bundles and copied them manually into my project.
I rarely need to modify dependencies. However with application bundles, I always have to customize the views and controllers, so they are meant to be modified in all the projects they are used.

I want to improve the way I manage these bundles and thought of using Composer. However, it does not comply very well with the application bundles, as you are not supposed to modify the packages. I would need to be able to install packages for once, then ignore them in the next updates (they become part of the application source code).

I could add some override mechanism (copy classes to another directory, which would override the default bundle classes) as Symfony does I think, but I don't like this idea. It just adds unnecessary complexity.

Could use another bundles management system, or even a custom one, but then this means no access to Composer packages, which would be great.

Using Composer for dependencies and another system for the application bundles would be messy..

How would you handle it?

Answer (score 0):

It it should run on unix, use  apt, yum, yast ...

Simply try to build your own dep / rpm pakages.

Build foreach application bundle and depencencies bundle.
That add at theapplication bundle the depencencies bundle as depends.

Or do you looking for something like pear?